# How do I find out which cloud service a site is hosted on?

Tags: web, cloud, hosting

I'd like to find out whether a site is hosted in a cloud service like AWS or Google Cloud or not. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check whois records online for any website, and check DNS pointing from which you will get idea about the provider where it is pointing.  Or simply use third party websites like https://hostingchecker.com to find the hosting provider.